# Crossfading videos with audio using FFmpeg results unsync audio

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I'd like to crossfade two videos with audio, the first one,`first.mkv`, is (20s) long and the second one,`second.mkv`, has unknown duration. Since I want transition start at 19 sec of the first video with the duration of 1 sec, I tried the following command using `xfade` filter for video and `acrossfade` filter for audio.

`ffmpeg -i first.mkv -i second.mkv -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]xfade=transition=fade:duration=1:offset=19[v];[0:a][1:a]acrossfade=duration=1[a]" -map "[v]" -map "[a]" output.mkv`

But, in second part of (ie. after 20 sec) the output video, the audio and video are out of synchro. Audio is ahead and video is delayed.

Why is this happen and how to fix it? Thanks.

Update: Here is the complete log.

````
  Metadata:
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.47.100
  Duration: 00:00:20.02, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4101 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23.98 fps, 23.98 tbr, 1k tbn, 47.95 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.93.100 libx264
      DURATION        : 00:00:20.020000000
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: vorbis, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      ENCODER         : Lavc58.93.100 libvorbis
      DURATION        : 00:00:20.000000000
Input #1, matroska,webm, from 'second.mkv':
  Metadata:
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.47.100
  Duration: 00:05:55.46, start: -0.007000, bitrate: 4221 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 60 fps, 60 tbr, 1k tbn, 120 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      HANDLER_NAME    : ISO Media file produced by Google Inc.
      DURATION        : 00:05:55.434000000
    Stream #1:1(eng): Audio: opus, 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:05:55.461000000
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (h264) -> xfade:main
  Stream #0:1 (vorbis) -> acrossfade:crossfade0
  Stream #1:0 (h264) -> xfade:xfade
  Stream #1:1 (opus) -> acrossfade:crossfade1
  xfade -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
  acrossfade -> Stream #0:1 (libvorbis)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast LZCNT SSSE3 SSE4.2
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] profile High 4:4:4 Predictive, level 4.0, 4:4:4 8-bit
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] 264 - core 155 r2917 0a84d98 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2018 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x1:0x111 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=0 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=4 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=23 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, matroska, to 'output.mkv':
  Metadata:
    MINOR_VERSION   : 0
    COMPATIBLE_BRANDS: iso6avc1mp41
    MAJOR_BRAND     : dash
    encoder         : Lavf58.47.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (H264 / 0x34363248), yuv444p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 23.98 fps, 1k tbn, 23.98 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.93.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
    Stream #0:1: Audio: vorbis (libvorbis) (oV[0][0] / 0x566F), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.93.100 libvorbis
frame=  720 fps= 15 q=-1.0 Lsize=   15257kB time=00:00:29.99 bitrate=4166.4kbits/s dup=0 drop=359 speed=0.642x    
video:14914kB audio:320kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:4kB muxing overhead: 0.151794%
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] frame I:11    Avg QP:18.59  size: 97377
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] frame P:266   Avg QP:22.33  size: 37075
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] frame B:443   Avg QP:25.85  size:  9792
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] consecutive B-frames:  6.4% 29.2% 16.7% 47.8%
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] mb I  I16..4: 45.1%  0.0% 54.9%
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] mb P  I16..4: 15.4%  0.0% 10.9%  P16..4: 36.3%  9.8%  3.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:24.5%
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] mb B  I16..4:  1.3%  0.0%  1.4%  B16..8: 35.2%  2.8%  0.4%  direct: 0.9%  skip:57.9%  L0:41.3% L1:55.1% BI: 3.5%
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] coded y,u,v intra: 34.8% 22.0% 13.1% inter: 5.9% 2.5% 1.3%
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] i16 v,h,dc,p: 39% 22% 13% 26%
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 27% 19% 17%  6%  7%  7%  6%  6%  4%
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] Weighted P-Frames: Y:2.3% UV:2.3%
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] ref P L0: 64.7% 16.1% 13.7%  5.4%  0.0%
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] ref B L0: 89.8%  8.9%  1.4%
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] ref B L1: 98.2%  1.8%
[libx264 @ 0x55c214e9e940] kb/s:4068.15```
````

Comment: Show the complete log.

Comment: @llogan I don't see any error output in terminal. Do you mean this.

`[libx264 @ 0x56147a307480] frame I:4     Avg QP:19.43  size:166846
[libx264 @ 0x56147a307480] frame P:203   Avg QP:22.83  size: 29284
[libx264 @ 0x56147a307480] frame B:392   Avg QP:25.28  size:  5180
[libx264 @ 0x56147a307480] consecutive B-frames:  1.2% 32.4%  7.0% 59.4%
[libx264 @ 0x56147a307480] mb I  I16..4: 54.7%  0.0% 45.3%
[libx264 @ 0x56147a307480] mb P  I16..4: 17.4%  0.0%  2.4%  P16..4: 34.4%  7.4%  3.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:35.4%
[libx264 @ 0x56147a307480] mb B  I16..4:  0.7%  0.0%  0.1%  B16..8: 26.3% `

Comment: That's part of it but the whole output is needed.

Comment: @llogan Question updated with log.

Comment: Make sure that duration of video is really exactly 20 seconds and that both frames per second of video inputs are same. Filter needs same constant frames per second on both inputs to work properly.